# Сохранение настроек приложения / Qt 5.8.0

Tags: c++, база-данных, qt, firebird

У меня программа при установке должна создавать локальную базу данных, для хранения настроек самой программы. Мне нужно где то сохранить, например, наименование всех таблиц для этой локальной базы. Возможно в файле ресурсов.

Для хранения всех настроек приложения был сделан класс - древовидная модель.
Эта модель подключается к локальной базе и считывает все настройки в соответствующие узлы модели. Если мне нужно получить настройки для подключения к базе данных то я запрашиваю узел с настройками у модели и передаю его в класс работающий с базой данных.

Ступор на том что есть настройки (как вышеупомянутые наименования таблиц) которые существуют до создания локальной базы. Я еще не знаю какие еще будут настройки, но уже видно что хотя бы наименования этих настроек уже будут иметься до её создания. Отсюда вопрос, где их сохранять и потом перенести уже в созданную базу.

То есть мой вышеупомянутый класс после вызова какого ни будь метода initializationApplication() должен где то получить "настройки для создания хранилища настроек".

Answer (score 1):

Есть QSettings, с его помощью можно читать и сохранять в .ini файл, например. Использовать с помощью этого класса можно пары ключ/значение, ключ - QString, значение - QVariant, то есть по сути что угодно.
Из доки:
"On all platforms, if you want to read an INI file directly, you can use the QSettings constructor that takes a file name as first argument and pass QSettings::IniFormat as second argument."